# Is there such a thing as the second-order theory of a structure?

Tags: logic, model-theory, second-order-logic

Given a structure, say for example, $(\mathbb{R};+,*,0,1,<)$, I know the definition of the first-order theory of that structure. But is there such a thing as the second-order theory of a structure, and if so, what is the definition of it?

Comment: If the language is based on Second Order Logic...

Comment: The second order theory of a structure is the set of all sentences of second-order logic which are true in that structure. What else could it be?